# Pandas: adding column with the length of other column as value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add an additional column to an existing dataframe that has the length of the 'seller_name' column as its value.

The output should be like so:

```
seller_name    name_length
-------------|-------------
Rick         |      4
Hannah       |      6
```

However, I'm having difficulty getting the code right.

```
df['name_length']  = len(df['seller_name'])
```

just gives me the length of the entire column (6845)
And

```
df['nl']  = df[len('seller_name')]
```

Throws a KeyError.

Does anyone know the correct command to achieve my goal?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the `.str` string accessor to perform string operations on DataFrames.  In particular, you want [`.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df['name_length']  = df['seller_name'].str.len()
```

The resulting output:

```
  seller_name  name_length
0        Rick            4
1      Hannah            6
```

Answer (score 13):

Say you have this data:

```
y_1980 = pd.read_csv('y_1980.csv', sep='\t')

     country  y_1980
0     afg     196
1     ago     125
2     al      23
```

If you want to calculate the length of any column you can use:

```
y_1980['length'] = y_1980['country'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
print(y_1980)

     country  y_1980  length
 0     afg     196       3
 1     ago     125       3
 2     al      23       2
```

This way you can calculate the length of any columns you desire.

Comment: The pandas built-in methods are more robust than using `apply`.  For example, this method will raise a TypeError if NaN is present in the string column, but the built-in `.str.len` will handle NaN.

Comment: this helped me when the column was a list