# Pandas creating a column which counts the length of a previous column entries without getting a Set Copy Warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I look at the answer to a similiar question as shown in this link: [Pandas: adding column with the length of other column as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815768/pandas-adding-column-with-the-length-of-other-column-as-value)

I come across an issue where the solution its suggesting i.e

```
df['name_length'] = df['seller_name].str.len()
```

Throws the following warning

```
'''
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
'''
```

**My question is:** How could this be done inorder to prevent this warning from occuring? As in this command I would like to add a new column to the original dataframe not create some sort of copy of a slice.

Comment: Does the name_length column already exist?

Comment: No so this is a new column which I want to calculate

Comment: df['name_length'] = df.loc[:,'seller_name'].str.len()

Answer (score 0):

I took a sample data set to test this issue in Python 3.8

Sample data
[image]

here is the same code which you ran
df['name_length'] = df['seller_name'].str.len()

there was no error
[image]

Comment: OP is asking about the warning.