# Create multiple columns at once based off of existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe `df`:

```
     name  class   
1     Bob  history
2   Chuck  math     
3   Daren  history  
4   Elisa  english 
5   Aaron  history 
6     Tom  math   
7     Dan  history 
8    Fred  english
```

I want to create two new columns **at once** which are simply the character length of the existing two columns. The result should look like this:

```
     name     class   name_len  class_len
1     Bob   history          3          7
2   Chuck      math          5          4
3   Daren   history          5          7
4   Elisa       art          5          3
5   Aaron   history          5          7
6     Tom      math          3          4 
7     Dan   history          3          7
8    Fred  business          4          8
```

I've tried to use for comprehension to generate the lists at once, such as so:

```
df[["1", "2"]] = [df[name].apply(len) for name in posts.columns]
```

but I get

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I would like to do more complex operations and create lots of new columns from pre-existing columns as such, and do not want to manually create each new column one at a time. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: adding column with the length of other column as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815768/pandas-adding-column-with-the-length-of-other-column-as-value)

Comment: I've just edited my post for clarity. I wanted to know if it was possible to create multiple new columns **at once** :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `apply`, `.str.len()` should work:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[f"{col}_len"] = df[col].str.len()

df
    name    class  name_len  class_len
1    Bob  history         3          7
2  Chuck     math         5          4
3  Daren  history         5          7
4  Elisa  english         5          7
5  Aaron  history         5          7
6    Tom     math         3          4
7    Dan  history         3          7
8   Fred  english         4          7
```

Comment: Alternative: `df = df.join(df.apply(lambda s: s.str.len()).add_suffix('_len'))`

Comment: @mozway Nice alternative. That works too :)