# How to create a column that stores the string size of another column?

Tags: python, dataframe, list

I am learning Python and I need to create a new column that stores the string size of another column of a dataframe, but I don't would like using Pandas or totalization function, is there other way?

I can do this with a list, but I can't with a dataframe. I used a list to show what I want.

```
data = [{'x': 'abc'}, {'x': 'defgh'}, {'x': 'ijklmnop'}, {'x': 'qrs'}]
for item in data:
    item['num_caracteres'] = len(item['x'])
print(type(data))
```

How can I adapt this code to use it with a dataframe?

Comment: Your question is to create a column that stores string size of other column, but your code just prints the data type. would you like data type or string length?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: adding column with the length of other column as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815768/pandas-adding-column-with-the-length-of-other-column-as-value)

Answer (score 0):

using your data list, you can grab the values and find the lengths of them and put them into a list with list comprehension. Then make a new column with values from that list

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'x': 'abc'}, {'x': 'defgh'}, {'x': 'ijklmnop'}, {'x': 'qrs'}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) # make the data frame with your data

lengths = [len(list(x.values())[0]) for x in data] # get lengths of strings
df['lengths'] = lengths # make new column with lengths list
print(df)
```